# oracle sql select script help

Tags: sql, oracle

Can any one please help with select script?

desired outcome

```
 TABLENAME, ATTRIBUTE, NULLABLE, DATATYPE, LENGTH, DESC, HELP_TEXT having count(datadic.ATTRIBUTE)>1  (because these can only be unique)
```

and is not unique to any other attribute (not include DDKEY and SerNo) with the same value.

i.e

```
 TABLE2 ADDR4 NULL VARCHAR2 15 Unit Address Line 4 Unit address line 4 
 TABLE1 ADDR4 NULL VARCHAR2 30 Unit Address Line 4 Unit address line 4
```

I am trying to get my head around nested queries

Real life senerio I want to see if my database has any attributes with different values in different tables a sort of house keeping exercise.

I have 154 table 700 attributes

so far

```
 select attribute,count(DATADIC.ATTRIBUTE) as "ATTRIBUTE" 
 from "DATADIC" "DATADIC"
 group by DATADIC.ATTRIBUTE 
 having count(datadic.ATTRIBUTE)>1)
 order by count(DATADIC.ATTRIBUTE)
```

then

```
 select TABLENAME,ATTRIBUTE,NULLABLE, DATATYPE, LENGTH, DESC, HELP_TEXT 
 from datadic 
 where      
 attribute in
 (select attribute,count(DATADIC.ATTRIBUTE) as "ATTRIBUTE" 
   from "DATADIC" "DATADIC"
   group by DATADIC.ATTRIBUTE
   having count(datadic.ATTRIBUTE)>1)
   order by count(DATADIC.ATTRIBUTE)
```

### has too many values

```
 desc
 DATADIC.
  DDKEY Number 
  SER Number 
  TABLENAME Varchar2 15 
  ATTRIBUTE Varchar2 25
  NULLABLE Varchar2 10 
  DATATYPE Varchar2 15  
  LENGTH number(7,3) 
  DESCRIPTION Varchar2 30
  HELP_TEXT Varchar2 1000
```

### sample data

```
556 5 TABLE2 ADDR1 NULL VARCHAR2 30 Unit Address Line 1 Unit address line 1 
545 5 TABLE1 ADDR1 NULL VARCHAR2 30 Unit Address Line 1 Unit address line 1 
546 6 TABLE1 ADDR2 NULL VARCHAR2 30 Unit Address Line 2 Unit address line 2 
557 6 TABLE2 ADDR2 NULL VARCHAR2 30 Unit Address Line 2 Unit address line 2 
547 7 TABLE1 ADDR3 NULL VARCHAR2 30 Unit Address Line 3 Unit address line 3 
558 7 TABLE2 ADDR3 NULL VARCHAR2 30 Unit Address Line 3 Unit address line 3 
559 8 TABLE2 ADDR4 NULL VARCHAR2 15 Unit Address Line 4 Unit address line 4 
548 8 TABLE1 ADDR4 NULL VARCHAR2 30 Unit Address Line 4 Unit address line 4
```

### useful script

```
CREATE TABLE  "DATADIC" 
(   "DDKEY" NUMBER, 
"SER" NUMBER, 
"TABLENAME" VARCHAR2(15), 
"ATTRIBUTE" VARCHAR2(25), 
"NULLABLE" VARCHAR2(10), 
"DATATYPE" VARCHAR2(15), 
"LENGTH" NUMBER(7,3), 
"DESCRIPTION" VARCHAR2(30), 
"HELP_TEXT" VARCHAR2(1000), 
 CONSTRAINT "DATADIC_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("DDKEY") ENABLE
)
```

/

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER  "bi_DATADIC" 
before insert on "DATADIC"              
for each row 
begin  
  for c1 in ( 
   select "DATADIC_SEQ".nextval next_val 
    from dual 
  ) loop 
  :new."DDKEY" :=  c1.next_val; 
 end loop; 
end;

/
ALTER TRIGGER  "bi_DATADIC" ENABLE
/
```

### data csv

```
 556,5,TABLE2,ADDR1,NULL,VARCHAR2,30,Unit Address Line 1,Unit address line 1
 557,6,TABLE2,ADDR2,NULL,VARCHAR2,30,Unit Address Line 2,Unit address line 2
 558,7,TABLE2,ADDR3,NULL,VARCHAR2,30,Unit Address Line 3,Unit address line 3
 559,8,TABLE2,ADDR4,NULL,VARCHAR2,15,Unit Address Line 4,Unit address line 4
 545,5,TABLE1,ADDR1,NULL,VARCHAR2,30,Unit Address Line 1,Unit address line 1
 546,6,TABLE1,ADDR2,NULL,VARCHAR2,30,Unit Address Line 2,Unit address line 2
 547,7,TABLE1,ADDR3,NULL,VARCHAR2,30,Unit Address Line 3,Unit address line 3
 548,8,TABLE1,ADDR4,NULL,VARCHAR2,30,Unit Address Line 4,Unit address line 4
```

updated data is now using this query but I need not make the not unique

`select * from ( 
select TABLENAME, 
       ATTRIBUTE, 
       NULLABLE,

       DATATYPE,

       LENGTH,

       DESCRIPTION,

       HELP_TEXT, 
       count(*) over (partition by attribute) attr_count

  from datadic 
) where attr_count > 1`

TABLENAME   ATTRIBUTE   NULLABLE    DATATYPE    LENGTH  DESCRIPTION     HELP_TEXT       ATTR_COUNT 
TABLE2      ADDR1       NULL        VARCHAR2    30 Unit Address Line 1  Unit address line 1     2 
TABLE1      ADDR1       NULL        VARCHAR2    30 Unit Address Line 1  Unit address line 1     2 
TABLE1      ADDR2       NULL        VARCHAR2    30 Unit Address Line 2  Unit address line 2     2 
TABLE2      ADDR2       NULL        VARCHAR2    30 Unit Address Line 2  Unit address line 2     2 
TABLE1      ADDR3       NULL        VARCHAR2    30 Unit Address Line 3  Unit address line 3     2 
TABLE2      ADDR3       NULL        VARCHAR2    30 Unit Address Line 3  Unit address line 3 2 
TABLE2      ADDR4       NULL        VARCHAR2    30 Unit Address Line 4  Unit address line 4     2 
TABLE1      ADDR4       NULL        VARCHAR2    30 Unit Address Line 4  Unit address line 4     2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> select TABLENAME,ATTRIBUTE,NULLABLE,
>   DATATYPE, LENGTH, DESC, HELP_TEXT from
>   datadic where attribute in (select
>   attribute,count(DATADIC.ATTRIBUTE) as
>   "ATTRIBUTE" from "DATADIC" "DATADIC"
>   group by DATADIC.ATTRIBUTE having
>   count(datadic.ATTRIBUTE)>1) order by
>   count(DATADIC.ATTRIBUTE)

You are getting a too many values because the query is expecting one column after the "IN" Clause. Try the following query to get all the rows in the table with an attribute that has occurred more than once.

```
select TABLENAME,
       ATTRIBUTE,
       NULLABLE, 
       DATATYPE, 
       LENGTH, 
       DESC, 
       HELP_TEXT 
  from datadic 
  where attribute in 
  (
  select attribute from (
  select attribute,
         count(DATADIC.ATTRIBUTE) as "ATTRIBUTE" 
   from "DATADIC" "DATADIC" 
   group by DATADIC.ATTRIBUTE 
   having count(datadic.ATTRIBUTE)>1) 
   order by count(DATADIC.ATTRIBUTE)
   )
  )
```

You can make good use of Analytic functions to answer this query in a simpler way.

```
select * from (
select TABLENAME,
       ATTRIBUTE,
       NULLABLE, 
       DATATYPE, 
       LENGTH, 
       DESC, 
       HELP_TEXT,
       count(*) over (partition by attribute) attr_count 
  from datadic
) where attr_count > 1
```

Comment: select * from ( 
select TABLENAME, 
       ATTRIBUTE, 
       NULLABLE,  
       DATATYPE,  
       LENGTH,  
       DESCRIPTION,  
       HELP_TEXT, 
       count(*) over (partition by attribute) attr_count  
  from datadic 
) where attr_count > 1

Comment: amend attribute desc , this gives me the list now to work on and is not unique to any other attribute (not include DDKEY and SerNo) with the same value.

Comment: using not unique across more than one attribute is that possible?

Comment: Not quite sure I get your question here.. I am assuming the data CSV that you provided before is the input.. Can you also provide the expected output? That will clea a lot of things up.

Comment: TABLE2 ADDR4 NULL VARCHAR2 15 Unit Address Line 4 Unit address line 4  
 TABLE1 ADDR4 NULL VARCHAR2 30 Unit Address Line 4 Unit address line 4    is expected output because the attributes match but the rest of the values do not less DDKEY and SerNo